# CAD Rigging Best Practices - parenting, joining mesh objects, etc

Tags: rigging

I'm working on a couple vizualization projects with CAD models and was wondering about best practices for rigging gantries.

The model has around 4k individual parts, mostly fasteners. QOL select same size addon is crucial to sorting these...

I have certain parts that need to move together, and I'm wondering about best practices here. Should I

1. Parent fasteners and small objects that need to move to a master object (arm or gantry) that can be parented to a bone.
2. Parent all objects that need to move to that single bone.

It seems either method involves digging through some heirarchies to make changes.
You can see here the result of parenting many small objects to one bone.
[image]

As a general question, is blender performance impacted by the number of objects, or the number of vertices in a scene as a whole? I have a bunch of parts that I ~could~ join together; It would make rigging easier, but I'm wondering if that is useful with the trade off of annoying material assignment.